# Finding and removing old mysql-bin files

Tags: windows, mysql

I am running a MySQL server on Windows 8. The MySQL directory requires 118 GB of space and has a lot of 1 GB mysql-bin files that haven't been modified for years according to the file system.

All of my databases combined are not large enough to warrant a 118 GB footprint so I suspect the server failed to delete some old bin files.

How can I only delete all of the mysql-bin files that are no longer in use by existing databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you should check is if binary logging is still enabled

```
mysql> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

These two commands will give you the list of binary logs it sees and the then the current binary log;

I cannot tell you how to delete the logs by database usage, but I can tell you three other ways:

## 1) DELETE ALL LOGS

The command to hose every binary log is

```
mysql> RESET MASTER;
```

That's all.

## 2) DELETE LOGS BY BINLOG NAME

If you see 118 binary logs, you can select which log to delete up to. For example, if the binary logs have the form `mysql-bin.000118`, you can delete up to the 100th log using

```
mysql> PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.000100`';
```

## 3) DELETE LOGS BY DATE AND TIME

Suppose you want to delete all logs but keep everything from midnight 5 days ago. Run this:

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND - INTERVAL 5 DAY;
```

or

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE '2014-07-11 00:00:00';
```

This will let mysqld figure out which binary logs to delete.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Interestingly, I get the error `ERROR 1381 (HY000): You are not using binary logging` when I try to `SHOW BINARY LOGS`